# Generic entities to load data from flat file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Essentially I have two different flat files Credit & Account with different record structures. I have created separate entities for their Header, Detail and Footer records and for the whole file.

File Account:

```
namespace Data.Entities
{
    [FlatFileContainerRecord(RecordLength = 100)]
    public class AccountFlatFile
    {
        public AccountHeader Header { get; set; }
        public List<Data.Entities.AccountDetail> Details { get; set; }
        public AccountFooter Control { get; set; }
        public AccountFlatFile()
    {
        Details = new List<AccountDetail>();
 }
```

File Credit:

```
namespace Data.Entities
{
    [FlatFileContainerRecord(RecordLength = 90)]
    public class CreditFlatFile
    {
        public CreditHeader Header { get; set; }
        public List<Data.Entities.CreditDetail> Details { get; set; }
        public CreditFooter Control { get; set; }
        public CreditFlatFile()
    {
        Details = new List<CreditDetail>();
    }
}
```

I created a generic job to execute the files. This is where I am stuck.

```
 foreach (string file in incomingFile)
 {
      GenericFile<T> genericFile = new GenericFile<T>();                
      using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
       {
            **genericFile = serializer.Deserialize<GenericFile<T>>(stream);**
       }

       if (genericFile.Details.Count > 0)
       {
               System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, genericFile.Details.Count, parallelOptions, index =>
                {

                     Repo.Upsert(genericFile.Details[index]);
                 });
         }
         else
         {
                        //log error
          }

 }
```

I am not sure how exactly the GenericFile class should look like and how it would  relate to the actual entity classes.

Hope I am clear with the question. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: This question is very unclear. I'm not sure what the problem is, or what you want us to do / propose.

Comment: I would like to know how I should define this GenericFile<T> class.

Comment: I might be missing it, but I can't really see anywhere that talks much about what you want that class to do/behave - so.... how would *we* know?

Comment: This class should just act as a generic file structure. So wherever I use genericFile<T> it has to use the appropriate file structure. T being a flatfile entity . I am not very familiar with generics . An example of how that class should look like would help. Thanks

Comment: Those 2 types are broadly similar, but there is no *generic*-style commonality between them... generics in c# aren't like in C++ templates, so there would need to be a **lot** stronger relationship here (not just "has a Details property" etc... there's no easy answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is the generic structure I got.

I removed the Account and Credit flatfile entities and now have only the detailrecord entities for those two.

```
namespace Data.Entities
{
   [FlatFileContainerRecord(RecordLength = 157)]
    public class FlatFile<FlatFileHeader, DT, FlatFileFooter> 
    {
       public FlatFileHeader Header { get; set; }
       public List<DT> Details { get; set; }
       public FlatFileFooter Control { get; set; }
       public FlatFile()
    {
        Details = new List<DT>();
    }
}
```